# Increase player moving speed while holding Left Shift

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this piece of code from my `PlayerMovement.cs` script:

```
float speed = 6f;

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
   speed = 12f;
else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
   speed = 6f;

Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
Debug.Log("Moved with a speed of " + speed);
```

I only included the moving part. It also has some "jump on space code", which I didn't want to include because I felt that it was useless.

The problem is, player's always moving with a speed of `6f`. It only outputs "Moved with a speed of `12f`" when I press the key. When I press it for 3 times, and I walk for 5 minutes with the key held, `12f` is only outputted 3 times. It seems that I only receive `12f` speed for one second, when I hit the key, then it goes back to `6f`. The "running" speed cannot even be observed when testing the game. I needed to type it in the log and see if it works.

What can I do for the player to "run" when he's holding `Left Shift`? Thank you.

Comment: Are you calling this code in `Update()`?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov yes

Comment: Try `GetKey` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958153/8564999). That's because `GetKeyDown` triggers only on the frame that the button was pressed, not on subsequent frames that it was held

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix this by doing this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
speed = 12f;
else
speed = 6f;
```

If you hold the button it will stay at 12f, if you release it it will go back to 6f

If you want to change it also when you press just one time you can do also:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
speed = 12f;
else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
speed = 6f;
else
speed = 6f;
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is you are always setting  `speed = 6f;` you should not define the speed in the same function. otherwise if you want it like that you should'nt use `GetKeyDown` but `GetKey`